# com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 2 path $

Tags: android, api, android-volley, malformed

**During Login time i got this error, please don't downgrade this if you know any solution please guide me. I also checked different stack overflow post but they all are talking about trim the string or other solution with retrofit but i can't solve it. I use volley.**

My Json File:-

```
{
  "error": false,
  "user": [
    {
      "user_id": "123",
      "customer_name": "Abc",
      "email": "abc@example.com",
      "salt": "123abc",
      "phone": "1234567890",
      "address": "Enter Address",
      "postal_code": "1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

**This is my Java Class :-**

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Boolean... booleen) {
        ExampleApi exampleApi = new ExampleApi();
        LoginUser result;
        try {
            result = exampleApi.loginPost(sharedPreferences.getString("abc_id", ""), semail, fcmToken, spassword);
            Gson gson = new Gson();                           
            String json = gson.toJson(result);
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            Log.e("result1", String.valueOf(jObj));
            if (jObj.getString("error").equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("user");
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                 return "true";
                 }else {
                String errormsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                return errormsg;
            }
            } catch (ApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("error", e.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
```

Comment: Can you edit question and post `LoginUser` class.

Comment: Need to investigate `loginPost` and `LoginUser`. Can you add those?

Comment: I also use this way but it's also not working:-                                                                                      
Gson gson = new Gson();
String result1 = String.valueOf(result);
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(result1));
reader.setLenient(true);
String json = gson.fromJson(reader, UserInfo.class);
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);

Comment: can you post the error log?

Comment: E/error: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 2 path $ @Sajith

Answer (score 1):

Can you try initializing Gson as below

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();
```

> Possibly there could be an issue in the expected JSON.

Comment: There can be issue in response content type. It should be`application/json`

Comment: Thank u for replies, but it's already application/json ("accept: application/json") @Vir Rajpurohit

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the properties of  `user` object (`user_id, customer_name. etc`) are in correct format which is equal to the object received as response.

ps:  If `user_id` is an `Integer` in your `user` object also it should be an `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was generated because of non UTF-8 json file encoding. When I convert it to UTF-8 all started to work.